# port or not to port

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new to ROS and seems there is a fundamental thing I can't understand please help:

If on a system, say Android, I'm running the 'core' of ROS, could I write a node on another system?

To me the answer seems to be 'yes', as I runned the ubuntu-arduino hello world tutorial, well, the cor is on ubuntu and node handler is being executed on arduino independently.

If this is right, then I could port a minimum software to any other processor (wish for Broadcom, for a router with OpenWRT), right?

What is the degree of complexity there, more than 10 files needed to be implemented, so that I run 1 node on anther system, yes, no, comments?

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43273/port-or-not-to-port/) by [rosgreeting](https://answers.ros.org/users/3122/rosgreeting/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "roscore" is mostly just an XML-RPC server that helps ROS nodes on the network establish connections between each-other. It doesn't matter what platform a ROS node is running on as long as it can communicate over the network.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't worked with it myself, but [eros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros) might be a place to look if you're looking for truly minimal ROS installs which can communicate via XML-RPC calls with the ROS network.

There are two other widely used options which allow devices to communicate with a ROS system without using XML-RPC calls. Those are [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial) (typically used on Arduino or other lightweight chips) and [rosbridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge) (typically used in web clients).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2